# SQL Update with join and case conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to update a table.

My table structures is:

- `MainTable`:

  ```
  id | status | type | user
  ```
- `OtherTable`:

  ```
  id | flag
  ```

Here I want to update all `status` and `user` field of `MainTable` excluding where `status='Stop'` and where `flag` on `OtherTable` not set i.e `0`, but how?

`OtherTable` hold value for `type='EMP'` only.

UPDATE: I want to update all `MainTable` records with a conditional check when `type ='EMP'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart Answer is given by @Asif
 
 Here is the simpler/alternate way suits my requirement

```
 `update MainTable
  set status='someStatus'
  where 
  status!='Stop'
  and check_type!='EMP'

  update MainTable
  set status='someStatus'
  from MainTable inner join OtherTable on OtherTable.id=MainTable.id
  where 
  OtherTable.flag=1`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update MT set user='someuser', status = "somestatus" 
FROM MainTable MT
Join
(
Select * 
from MainTable MT1
Join Othertable OT on MT1.Id = OT.Id
AND OT.Flag = 0
and  MT1.type='EMP'
Union All
Select * 
from MainTable MT2
WHERE MT2.id not in (Select ID FROM Othertable where Flag = 0)
and  MT2.type='EMP'
) tblOther
on MT.ID = tblOther.ID
```

Comment: change your condition type='EMP' as per your required.

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery....

```
Update MainTable Set user="" where status='STOP' and id in (select id from OtherTable 
where Flag!=0)
```

Comment: ya rty..but i used 'IN, now and unfortunatelly no result